# Are small files worth compressing on the server

Tags: php, apache, gzip

Is there a point (in terms of file size) where it is no longer useful to use gzip, because the time needed for the server to compress and the browser to decompress balances out against the time saved sending the file compressed?

Because we are on a shared server and our hosting provider doesn't allow us to use Apache's compression, so we use PHP to gzip our pages.  It is easy enough to leave the php out of a small page file if there is a time advantage to be had.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is not a programming question, I don't think it's worth the bother. Just gzip everything and you'll be fine. Likely, a little too much compression isn't gonna be your main bottleneck.

Comment: My apologies if it isn't in the right area, wasn't sure where to ask such a question.

Answer (score 1):

Compression works better on text type files. If you compress css and js files you'll get benefit. But you should not **only compress** these files rather **compile them into a single unit and compress afterwords**.

For example if you have 50 css files of 20 bytes each, compressing only 20bytes will n not reduce the time at all. You should compile them into a single unit. That'll be 1000bytes file. Then compress it. This will also **reduce 49 http requests**.

Comment: Aggregating static resources is definitely a good idea but it's usually not the optimal solution. You may want to aggregate into several files and also add some smaller files directly to the main content instead of loading a file at all. The mod_pagespeed rules give a great insight into what's optimal for speed.

Comment: Not all rules are on-topic for compression

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PHP to zip files, make sure you send the proper headers for the browser to cache them. If they're dynamic files (php output), then, in my experience, always zipping them is better than sending them uncompressed

Answer (score 1):

I think for larger files (> 50KB) it makes sence to compress them in PHP. In my experience compression ration for text files (CSS, JS, static HTML) is at least 1:10 which is significant difference.

But I wouldn't recommend it for small files, because as you said your webserver doesn't gzip output automatically and PHP itself has some overhead (lunching process, allocation memory, compressing file, etc.) so I think from user point of view there wouldn't be any performance benefit. Just your server would generate more load.